# How can I use a document class in a single AS3 movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, generator, document

I have a confetti generator that I am tyring to add to a single movie clip within my flash file. The clip is masked and I want to have some graphics and text appear above the confetti (which will be above a background layer as well).

I purchased a decent script and have modified it to work with some original confetti artwork but I can't figure out how to use this class (or change it for use) in just the one movie clip. Pasting the class below. I've been stressing about this for a couple of hours now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.pixeljunkyard 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import caurina.transitions.*;
    import fl.motion.Color;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    //Create Heart Instance
    private var hearts:Heart;

    //Amount of hearts
    private var totalHearts:Number = 30;

    //Falling Speed
    private var speed:Number = 1.5;

    //Constructor
    public function Main() 
    {
        //Align top left for screen aspect ratio
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        //Loop through the amount of heart to be created
        for (var i = 0; i < totalHearts; i++)
        {
            //Create new heart
            var heart = new Heart();

            //Set Random value
            var randScale:Number = randRange(50, 100);
            var randRotation:Number = randRange( -180, 180);
            var randRotationY:Number = randRange( -360, 360);

            //Random position and scale
            heart.x = randRange(0, stage.stageWidth);
            heart.y = randRange( -stage.stageHeight, stage.stageHeight);
            heart.scaleX = randScale/100;
            heart.scaleY = randScale/100;

            //Name each heart with the number of creation
            heart.name = "heart" + i;

            var Low : int = 1;
            var High : int = 8;
            var myRandomNumber:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+High-Low))+Low;


            heart.gotoAndStop(myRandomNumber);

            //Add eventlisteners for interactions
            heart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, hit_heart);
            heart.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, change_shade);

            //Initial Animation
            Tweener.addTween(heart, {time:randRange(1,5)/speed, rotation:randRotation,rotationY:randRotationY,y:stage.stageHeight+(heart.height/2)+20, transition:"linear", onComplete:rebirth,onCompleteParams:[heart]} );

            //Add to Stage
            addChildAt(heart, i);

        }
    }

    //Change shade to give lighting effect
    private function change_shade(e:Event):void
    {
        //New color instance
        var c:Color = new Color();
        //Set properties
        c.brightness = e.target.rotation / 300;

        //Apply color to heart
        e.target.transform.colorTransform = c;

    }

    //Random Function
    private function randRange(min:Number, max:Number):Number 
    {
        var randomNum:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    //Interactive animation
    private function hit_heart(e:Event):void
    {
        Tweener.addTween(e.target, { time:randRange(1,3), rotationY:e.target.rotationY+180 } );
    }

    //Reset heart to top of the screen once fallen
    private function rebirth($heart:Heart):void
    {
        $heart.x = randRange(0, stage.stageWidth);
        $heart.y = -$heart.height;

        Tweener.addTween($heart, {time:randRange(1,5)/speed, rotation:randRange(-180,180),y:stage.stageHeight+($heart.height/2)+20, transition:"linear", onComplete:rebirth,onCompleteParams:[$heart]} );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your question needs to be more specific. I don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: This script only works when I call it form the document class blank in the properties of the flash movie. I haven't really learned to work with document classes and typically write what I need to write within the first frame of a movie. So there are two problems I'm having with this script. First, I need to be able to call it and start it up without setting the whole script as the document class for my swf, and I need to be able to restrict this to the contents of a movieclip so that I can mask it, place assets above it (text/graphics), and assets behind it(a background layer).

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it out yet. I got desperate enough to animate the confetti by hand because I couldn't find another solution that granted me enough control. While I really want to try this out and I will soon, I need to do so before I accept the answer. Your time is hugely appreciated though and I hope to learn something here that will help me change my practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand your problem.

First of all, I suggest to never write code on the timeline, except simple stuff like `stop()` or `gotoAndPlay("loop")`.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to do the following:

1. Make a blank `MovieClip` in Flash IDE <kbd>Ctrl + F8</kbd>
2. Give it a linkage like this:
   [image: Add linkage for flash symbol]
3. Then click the edit button (marked with a red rectangle)
4. Open in Flash Professional if asked
5. Save the file in your .FLA directory and copy the contents of your Main.as file into this file
6. Remove the package name ("com.pixeljunkyard")
7. Change the `public class Main extends Sprite` to `public class ConfettiContainer extends MovieClip` and import `flash.display.MovieClip`

Now you have a class ConfettiContainer which does the same stuff that you Main.as file did. Don't forget to copy anything that this Main.as class uses from stage to your ConfettiContainer `MovieClip`.

You can now create and use it like this:

```
var confetti:ConfettiContainer = new ConfettiContainer();
addChild(confetti);
```

P.S. If you can't see `Export for Actionscript` option when creating a `Symbol` in Flash, click `Advanced`.

Comment: Still couldn't get this to work, but it might be something going on with my source file. Thanks for your time. Your advice is wonderfully thorough.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't a big help. Please let me know if I can assist you any further.